# Data not getting reflected in excel file without closing oledb connection c#

Tags: c#, excel-2010, oledbconnection

In Excel, during Insert/Update operations,data is not getting saved to excel file until OLEDB connection is open.When I close OLEDB connection the data is getting saved to Excel. What can be done to reflect changes to excel file without closing the OLEDB connection.

**Example:**Writing data to excel.

```
OledbConnection olecon=new OledbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=filepath;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;'");
olecon.open();
OledbCommand cmd=new OledbCommand("Insert into..;",olecon);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
olecon.close();
```

This piece of code will work fine.But If oledb connection is not closed(If you skip `olecon.close();`)the inserted data will not be seen on excel file until you close the connection.So my question is, How we can save data to excel without closing the oledb connection.

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be very helpful.

Also, if memory serves me correctly, C#'s integration with MSOffice products can be achieved through their interop assembly and has nothing to do with an oledb connection.